# How do you activate the Android Emulator's screen-orientation switching to emulate responsiveness?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

This is a question that I actually know the answer to from discovery today, and I'd like to share the answer with you and also with my future self who might have forgotten.

So the problem is that by expectation, when the screen of the android emulator is rotated 90 degrees, you might expect the UI on display to also rotate 90 degrees automatically, but by default this does not happen, and there are some steps that need to be taken in order for the wanted rotation to begin occurring.

I did a Google search and some results pointed to Stack, but none of the results were recent and none of the results resolved my problem.

In the search results were some words I noticed, and those words helped me to find the solution I now share : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I learnt today is that after the emulator finishes loading, the screen can be pulled down to reveal a set of hidden options, one of which is "Auto-rotation" which by default is set to "off".

It's a slow drag to get it down, so starting at the top of the screen, hold your mouse click for about a second, and then slowly begin to pull/draw downwards.

The screen can be partially-drawn and fully drawn, so first get the screen partially-drawn, and then work on the latter drawing until the screen is fully drawn.

Illustrations below:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5.

[image]

I trust that this procedure is now explained and well illustrated ... Haaaappy Coding : )